# IP Address For Relay Connection

Tags: configuration

When I launch TOR and check the circuit that I'm connected to, more often than not, 'my browser' is connected to an IP in the USA (198.199.90.205) and then the other relays can be from any other country in the world pretty much. However, if I create a new relay for the connection, it always connects my browser through the 198.199.90.205 IP. The other relays change but this one doesn't. This has only started happening recently. Does anyone else have this problem?
Cheers